# ORA31011 - XML parsing Failed

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-attribute

I have a SQL script that Im building to make a structure, this is the oracle version Im working with "Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production", then this is the script:

```
XMLELEMENT("cbc:InvoicedQuantity", xmlattributes('PEN' as "/@unitCode"))
```

this is the line that give me the error. I think xml cant parse this characters "/" or "@", is there any solution for this? please, i need help.

Comment: I just tried this on Oracle 11gR2 and it worked fine. The exact query I tried was: 'select XMLELEMENT("cbc:InvoicedQuantity", xmlattributes('PEN' as "/@unitCode")) from dual;'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this, maybe it can help.

```
select replace(xmlelement("cbc:InvoicedQuantity", xmlattributes('PEN' as "
unitCode")),chr(10),'/@')
from dual;
```

The idea is to use line-break (or any other useless symbol) to replace it with the symbols needed later.